# NoSuchMethodError during StreamBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, snapshot, stream-builder

I am making a quiz app, and am trying to pull the quiz data from FireStore and display it as a stream on the page. Watching some tutorials, I have seen that it says to write "snapshot.data.documents[index].data[''], however- when doing this, I get an error that says:

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state:
_StreamBuilderBaseState<dynamic, AsyncSnapshot>#92653):
'documents'
method not found
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'
Arguments: []

This is my code below:

```
class _TeacherState extends State<Teacher> {

  Stream? quizStream;
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  DatabaseService databaseService = new DatabaseService();

  Widget quizList() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: quizStream,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            return snapshot.data == null
                ? Container()
                : ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return QuizTile(
                        noOfQuestions: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                        imageUrl:
                            snapshot.data.documents[index].data['quizImgUrl'],
                        title:
                            snapshot.data.documents[index].data['quizTitle'],
                        description:
                            snapshot.data.documents[index].data['quizDescription'],
                        id: snapshot.data.documents[index].data["quizID"],
                      );
                    });
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Initially, I was getting an error because the Stream was a non nullable type, and, even though I had written an initState function, it was giving me an error. I fixed this by placing a null check operator on the Stream quizStream. However, after doing this, this is when the NoSuchMethodError started popping up

Comment: Where you are initialising `quizStream`, can you add full widget code

Comment: Whatever type `snapshot.data` is doesn't have a `documents` field. If I had to guess, you're treating a `Map` as though this was JavaScript. But this is Dart, not JavaScript, and you need to do `snapshot.data['documents']` instead. Also if you're initializing your stream in `initState`, declare it as a `late Stream` instead of a `Stream?`.

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh here is the entire Repository: https://github.com/aleckovice/piddle_rolebased. I will add this to the question in a moment, there is just a queue to edit currently

Comment: @Abion47 here is the github repository: https://github.com/aleckovice/piddle_rolebased. I had it declared as a late Stream, and that was when I received an error "LateInitializationError: Field 'quizStream' has not been initialized" even though I had initialized it in initState

Comment: @EdinAleckovic Looking at the repo, you *aren't* initializing the stream in `initState`. You are initializing it in the `then` body of a future that happens to be fired within `initState`. There's a big difference.

Comment: Also, you're getting the stream from your database service which is returning a `Stream<QuerySnapshot>` from your FireStore service. [`QuerySnapshot` doesn't have a `documents` field.](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) You should use IntelliSense and follow the documentation of the packages you are using to avoid errors like this.

Comment: @Abion47 Will do! Thank you so much for your help and instruction

Answer (score 0):

You are trying ready documents from `QuerySnapshot` with variable `documents`, but actually documents will be collected from `docs`

Try with following code in place `ListView`

```dart
                 ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return QuizTile(
                        noOfQuestions: snapshot.data!.docs.length,//docs
                        imageUrl:
                            snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['quizImgURL'],//data will be accessed with ()
                        title:
                            snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['quizTitle'],
                        description:
                            snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['quizDescription'],
                        id: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()["quizID"],
                      );
                    });
```

Comment: I tried this, and then received the following error: 

"The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building:
Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'"

It is also not giving me any indication of what it was expected to be of type String, just that whatever 'it' is is of type Null

Comment: Updated, `quizImgUrl` -> `quizImgURL`

Comment: Thank you so much, its working now. All that is left is a RenderFlex error, but I know how to take care of this. Woohoo!